# Macro for pivot change filters have no effect

Tags: excel, vba

Community, need your help here, other than the fact the macro initially did nothing, I have now an error 1004: Application or object defined error!!
I updated my query to simplify and hoping to correct the no effect result from the macro, but now I made it worst.. any help please

```
Sub changeFilters()

Dim wsChart As Worksheet: Set wsChart = Sheets("Graph Data")
Dim wsPivot As Worksheet: Set wsPivot = Sheets("PCW_pivot")
Dim pt As PivotTable: Set pt = wsPivot.PivotTables("PCW1")
Dim pf As PivotField: Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[Range].[Geography].[Geography]")
Dim SelGeo As Variant: SelGeo = Sheets("Graph Data").Range("E3").Value

'turn on automatic update / calculation in the Pivot Table

With SelGeo <> "WW"
    pt.ManualUpdate = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    pf.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="[SelGeo]"
    pt.RefreshTable
    End With
With SelGeo = "WW"
.ClearAllFilters
  End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: `Case [SelGeo]` - `SelGeo` is a named Range. Is that a single Cell?  Also what do you mean by `"[Range].[Geography].[Geography]"`?

Comment: @BruceWayne - yes, the `SelGeo` is indeed a name Range located in "Graph data" cell (E3) - it is a combo box result. 
The `"[Range].[Geography].[Geography]"` is the Pivot Field name. As the pivot is now a Data model, I needed to change the Pivot field name initially as "Geography" to the one above after checking via macro recording to correct an Error 1004.

Comment: why would the `pf.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="[SelGeo]"` not working anymore in the updated macro above?